# Regex for custom GROUP BY statement

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a Java-compatible regex for custom GROUP BY statement to parse expressions like this:

`GROUP BY table1.feild1, table2.feild2 UNDER table3`

The idea is to get multiple "group by" tables somehow, along with a single "under" table.

I've tried something like this, but it does not work -

`^\s*group\s*by\s*([,]*[\s]*([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})\s{1,}under\s{1,}([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$`

I'm not even sure that it can be done in a single regex. Maybe it should be split?

Comment: What result do you want to achieve exactly? Need an example at least

Comment: @Sedo I want to match `table1.field1`, `table2.field2`... and a single `table3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex: `^\s*group\s+by\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?:,\s*[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*\s+)under\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hVUyqo/2)

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for the response. I tried that, result for the second group is `table 3`, exactly what I need. But the first group includes everything starting from GROUP BY. Is there a way to match only `table1.field1`, `table2.field2`, ...?

Comment: I have edited the answer to have `table1.feild1, table2.feild2, table3.field4 ` in `Group1` and `table3` in `Group 2`